# Подскажите что делает аннотация в JEE7

Tags: java, java-ee

Есть следующая аннотация @Accesstimeout. Вопрос что она делает? Если значение -1, метод будет выполняться пока занят потоком, бесконечно. Если 0, когда постучиться какой либо поток, в момент когда метод уже выполняется, то будет исключение. А что будет если значение указано положительное(5 секунд)? Метод выполняется заданное время, и обязательно передаст выполнение другому в очереди по окончанию этого времени? а если не передаст, то в таком случае выброситься исключение? Если раньше 5 секунд закончит выполнение метода то просто передаст выполнение следующему потоку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если указан таймаут в 5 секунд и ваш запрос запрос поступил тогда, когда обрабатывается другой запрос, то ваш запрос будет ждать. Если предыдущий запрос не выполнится за 5 секунд, вы получите исключение.